# How to find all keys in std::map having maximum values C++?

Tags: c++

For example, given a map

```
std::map<char, int> map{{'a', 5}, {'b', 3}, {'c', 2}, {'d', 5}};
```

I want to output the keys `'a'` and `'d'`, since they both have the maximum value in map.  How can I do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<char, int> map{{'a', 5}, {'b', 3}, {'c', 2}, {'d', 5}};
    // ???
}
```

Comment: To avoid attracting downvotes, I have included a code example for you.  Please review it and include it in your future questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `multimap` + `equal_range` query which is called for the highest key - can be extracted by `rbegin` method:

```
std::map<char,int> m{{'a',2},{'b',3},{'c',5},{'d',5}};
std::multimap<int,char> m2;
for (auto&& i : m)
    m2.insert(std::make_pair(i.second,i.first));
auto it = m2.rbegin(); // get the elem with the highest key
auto range = m2.equal_range(it->first);
for (auto it = range.first; it != range.second; ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << ", " << it->second << std::endl;
```

As output you will get:

```
    // 5 d
    // 5 c
```

Answer (score 2):

You should find what is the maximum number and then collect keys with that value.

This allows you to use least amount of memory (you don't have to copy everything, only what will be the result) and should be faster as you don't need to "sort" everything (by using another `std::*map` / `std::*set` object) or insert and remove to/from another container.

```
std::vector<char> maxValueKeys(const std::map<char, int>& input) {
    // Case when no data is present
    if (input.empty()) {
        return {};
    }

    // Find maximum value
    int max_value = input.begin()->second;
    for (const auto& entry : input) {
        if (entry.second > max_value) {
            max_value = entry.second;
        }
    }

    // Find all keys with maximum value
    std::vector<char> keys;
    for (const auto& entry : input) {
        if (entry.second == max_value) {
            keys.push_back(entry.first);
        }
    }

    return keys;
}
```